# Need to return the minimum value relative to a dynamic anchor point SQL

Tags: sql, analytics, partition, vertica

I'm trying to return a value based on it's proximity to a dynamic date value for an event using SQL.

Event: My store updates price on 7/30 to 6.99

-Competitor #1 updates their price to 6.75 on 7/29 (this would not be ranked given it precedes my price change)

-Competitor #1 updates their price to 6.99 on 8/2 (this would be ranked #1 relative to my price change)

-Competitor #1 updates their price to 7.99 on 8/3 (this would be ranked #2 relative to my price change)

Data:

```
Store | Price | Date | Rank (intended_output)

MyStore | 6.99 | 7/30/2021 | NULL (only computes for comp)

Comp1 | 6.75 | 7/29/2021 | NULL (precedes my change)

Comp1 | 6.99 | 8/2/2021 | 1

Comp1 | 7.99 | 8/3/2021 | 2
```

Comment: what is your expected result

Comment: updated the post with intended output.

Comment: You could calculate the date/time span difference and sort by (absolute) value.

Comment: That's an option but a suboptimal one (I believe). I have thousands of price changes in any given day and dozens on competitors. This would likely result in a many-to-many relationship which I join competitor data on my own. How would I reduce records down to a one to many relationship (my store vs each comp)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this..

I ran this in postgresql, the resultant output matches your expected output.

```
create table t(store varchar(50),price int, date1 date);

insert into t 
select 'MyStore',6.99,cast('2021-07-30' as date) union all
select 'Comp1',6.75,cast('2021-07-29' as date) union all
select 'Comp1',6.99,cast('2021-08-02' as date) union all
select 'Comp1',7.99,cast('2021-08-03' as date);

 select x.store
       ,x.price
       ,x.date1
       ,case when grp=1 then 
             row_number() over(partition by grp order by date1) 
        end as rnk
  from (
select t.*, case when date1 >'2021-07-30' then 1 else 0 end as grp
  from t
       )x

+=========+=======+============+========+
| store   | price | date1      | rnk    |
+=========+=======+============+========+
| Comp1   | 7     | 2021-07-29 | (null) |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+
| MyStore | 7     | 2021-07-30 | (null) |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+
| Comp1   | 7     | 2021-08-02 | 1      |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+
| Comp1   | 8     | 2021-08-03 | 2      |
+---------+-------+------------+--------+
```

link
https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/01e2add8ba6472ad944ee8d6b6481e88/

Comment: George Joseph has the right answer! Thank you!

Comment: Mark the answer by upvoting and setting it as accepted answer